# apache beam on dataflow: WriteToBigQuery doesnt work

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have an apache beam pipeline, written in python, that reads events from a kafka topic, does some curation, and write the cureted events to a bigquery table.

The pipeline runs properly when running locally with direct runner,
but not when running on dataflow.
On dataflow, I can see that messages are being read and curated properly from kafka, but when it comes to the bigquery step, I dont see any success/failure logs, nor new rows on the bigquery table.

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions


def curation_func(...):
    pass


# ...
beam_options = SetupOptions(...)
with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
    (
        pipeline
        | "read kafka events" >> kafkaio.KafkaConsume(...)
        | "curation" >> beam.Map(curation_func)
        | "write to bigquery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table="my_table",
            project="my_project",
            dataset="my_dataset",
            method="STREAMING_INSERTS",
            create_disposition="CREATE_NEVER",
            write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
        )
    )
```

Is there something wrong with my pipeline?
How can I see the logs of the bigquery step?

Comment: Hi @asafal, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/?hl=en). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.